# Cannot link to files from bower in meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor, zurb-foundation, bower

I am unable to link to files inside .meteor/local/bower in my meteor app.
I am using foundation-apps from bower which has only two files in its main section of .bower.json.

```
"main": [
    "dist/css/foundation-apps.css",
    "dist/js/foundation-apps.js"
]
```

I also need the /js/foundation-apps-templates.js to be included in my project.

I can edit the .bower.json but it is gitignored and won't work in other system or production.
I tried adding the cdn links of these files but meteor minifies everything at deployment and cdn version remains same, thus giving a conflict.
Is there any way of adding all these to my app and have it minified properly for production?